# fc -RI in precmd, now up-line-or-history doesn't work

Tags: zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

I'm using the option `INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME`. That doesn't work together with `SHARE_HISTORY`. So I thought I call `fc -RI` before each command. But now I can't access my history via `up-line-or-history` (bound to the Up key) anymore. The “history-substring-search” plugin from oh-my-zsh still works as well as the “zsh-autosuggestions” plugin. `history` prints the whole history.

Even if I now type a new command, I can't access it with the Up key.

```bsh
export HISTFILE="${ZDOTDIR}/.zsh_history"
export HISTSIZE=50000
export SAVEHIST=10000

setopt NO_SHARE_HISTORY EXTENDED_HISTORY INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME

function precmd_history
{
    fc -RI # Everything is fine when this line is commented.
}
precmd_functions+=precmd_history
```

Edit:
If I don't load the lib from oh-my-zsh (`robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh path:lib` in antibody), it works as expected. When I load oh-my-zsh and set `precmd_functions=()` it works, when I set `precmd_functions=(precmd_history)` it stops to work.

Comment: Works for me with this `.zshrc` on zsh 5.8. `Up` recalls the commands listed by `history`.

Comment: Thanks. I found out that it works for me if I don't load the lib from oh-my-zsh. (`robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh path:lib` in antibody).